# What more can we find out about the cause of an jQuery .ajax() failure when the usual error fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    error: function (jqXHR, exception, errorThrown) {
           
        // in the case which I am trying to debug ...

        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        // Outputs a 0 - not useful, general purpose 'network is down' and 3 other reasons

        console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
        // Outputs "error" - not useful

        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        // Outputs "undefined" - not useful

        console.log(exception);
        // Outputs "error" - not useful

        console.log(errorThrown);
        // Outputs "" - not useful

    });
```

Is there any way to get more information about what went wrong?

When `jqXHR.status` is `0`, that means the host is unreachable, but the thing is, it's connecting to the exact same host (on same `https` protocol) that it fetched the Javascript from a few milliseconds prior, so its really not likely to be down -- something else happened.

Thank you all, stay safe.

Edits:

- My question is asking how to find out *programmatically*; opening up the developer console is not an option.
- I have set CORS headers correctly.  This Ajax call works 998 out of 1000 times.

Comment: In your situation I would try to check with the network tab in the developer tool.
You can see the request and the actual response. Not sure if this will help you out...

Comment: Are you using HTTP2?

Comment: `jqXHR.status is 0` is the request same origin (**as the PAGE**) or cross origin? If the latter, probably a CORS issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Not a CORS issue, please see edit

Comment: try using `fetch` instead of `$.ajax` - perhaps the information you get with `fetch` will be better than whatever `jQuery` deems important